# Telegram.Bot error

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm using Telegram.Bot package [found here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telegram.Bot).

This error is occurring, and fails my robot:

> Error converting value "supergroup" to type 'Telegram.Bot.Types.ChatType'.
>   Path 'result[37].message.chat.type', line 39, position 316.

How do I diagnose and fix this problem?

Comment: What is your code at and around line 39?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library doesn't support `supergroup` chat type right now.
You should go to github and create issue, or find another library.

Comment: @NaserShahriari if this is an answer set it as answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in calling APIs, Update DLLs and VS to Vs 2015

or use this code in C#

```
  int offset = 0;
            while (true)
            {
            TryAgain:
                  try{
                Telegram.Bot.Types.Update[] updates = bot.GetUpdates(offset).Result;
                foreach (var update in updates)
                {
.. . . .. 
}
}

     catch (Exception ef)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ef.Message);
                if (ef.Message.Contains("Telegram.Bot.Types"))
                {
                    goto TryAgain; 
                }
            }
```